# Can I change my drive?

Tags: windows, lenovo-desktop-computer

I recently received a desktop computer ([Lenovo H420](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/desktops-and-all-in-ones/lenovo-h-series-desktops/lenovo-h420-desktop)) from someone. It's in perfect shape and works fine with start up. I went to get into Windows  but it is locked under a different user. I can't erase anything. Can I change the drive with a brand new one and solve the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Instead of asking if your proposed solution will work, ask how to solve your problem. You'll get much better results.

Comment: There should be a boot menu option to restore the factory default configuration. You will need to consult your computer or motherboard manual to find out how to do this.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just enable the built-in Administrator account and Reset your installation?

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo computers will frequently have a "one-key recovery" feature. This is a key on some laptop keyboards, but also a very tiny hole on the side of a laptop as well. If you provide an accurate model number, I can research the sequence for you, or you can search using the terms "lenovo one-key recovery" followed by your model number.

My own quick search presented a number of solutions and almost all of them point to laptop computers, but a few of them were generic enough to expect that it covers desktop units.

With the model number "in hand," it appears that it is necessary to press repeatedly the F2 key at startup. This should be initiated when you see the lenovo logo on the screen. Too much delay will place you into windows, too quickly may generate a keyboard error. The latter is less likely than the former.

It does not require that you be signed on as any user.

You ask if you can change your drive. Yes, you can, but you'll have a blank drive with no operating system, while the F2 method will erase the computer and re-install the OS from a clean slate.

If you decide to replace the drive, you can purchase recovery media (usually flash drive) from Lenovo. The 'net "wisdom" suggests a cost near US$50 as well as the delay involved in ordering, shipping and receiving.

Comment: Its Lenovo H420

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the drive - just wipe it and reinstall...

That will solve your issue.

But to answer your question, yes, you can replace the drive if you want :-)

Comment: How would I wipe and reinstall if I cant get in?

Comment: Get yourself an install disk, and when it asks if you want to format the disk, say yes

Answer (score 0):

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/HT077226 is the link to Lenovo One Key Recovery for your desktop. It will rewind Windows to how it was in the store, so you can create your own username and password and use it. This is far superior to replacing the drive and buying a new copy of Windows!

**Warning**: System Recovery will overwrite *all* of the data on the C: drive. To prevent loss of data, be sure to back up relevant data before performing the system recovery. If you think there's any other way to get the administrator password from the seller, please try that first!

Start by powering up.
1. Tap and release {**F2**} key repeatedly until you see **Lenovo Rescue System**.
2. Pick **OneKey Recovery**.
3. Instructions appear with a list of pre-done backups. Select the backup done at the factory.
4. Tell it to restore to the first drive, drive C:.
5. Pick **Next** to start the restore.
6. Please wait during the process of system recovery. *Don't interrupt the operation during the recovery process.*
7. After recovery is finished, it will tell you to restart the  desktop. Restart the PC and start Windows.